# How to set the numbered list ON by default in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am integrating ckeditor into my website. When the user starts to use it, I want to start using the numbered list immediately.

I read the docs at http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config and could not see an option to turn this on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor transforms a textarea element on your page into an editor, so you can set the initial text of that textarea element to a numbered list.

Here's the sample page from the [CKEditor Quick Start Guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation) with the initial text changed to a numbered list:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                <ol><li /></ol>
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```